# Can not create files in own user folder?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I installed OSX snowleopard new on my macbook. Now I have permission problems. I can not create a file as my own user in my own user folder.

I also tried disk utility with the "Repair Disk Permissions" function, which doesn't help.

Any ideas?

```
~ $ touch bla
touch: bla: Permission denied


Users $ ls -lae
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  admin   170 23 Okt 12:38 .
drwxr-xr-x  31 root  admin  1122 23 Okt 18:01 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     0 27 Jan  2010 .localized
drwxrwxrwt   4 root  wheel   136 23 Okt 15:01 Shared
drwx------@ 33 ber   staff  1122 28 Okt 14:50 ber
 0: group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown


~ $ ls -lae
total 160
drwx------@  33 ber   staff   1122 28 Okt 14:50 .
 0: group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown
drwxr-xr-x    5 root  admin    170 23 Okt 12:38 ..
-rw-------    1 ber   staff      3 23 Okt 12:38 .CFUserTextEncoding
-rw-r--r--@   1 ber   staff  21508 28 Okt 23:44 .DS_Store
drwx------  100 ber   staff   3400 28 Okt 17:46 .Trash
-rw-r--r--    1 ber   staff   1778 27 Okt 15:28 .profile
-rw-------    1 ber   staff   1024 23 Okt 16:55 .rnd
drwx------    7 ber   staff    238 23 Okt 18:26 .ssh
 0: group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown
drwx------+  15 ber   staff    510 28 Okt 15:27 Desktop
```

Comment: What does "echo $USER" give?

Comment: @Jay - It looks like the only user is 'ber'.  Are you thinking it might be something different?

Comment: Do you use FileVault?

Comment: @Jay as expected "echo $USER" returns my name (ber).

Comment: @Daniel Beck; I do not use FileVault.

Comment: It's just a good idea to make sure. Try removing the ACL and see if that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's the ACL. Try removing it with:

```
cd /Users/
chmod -a# 0 ber
```

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, here's mine (with a fairly fresh Snow Leopard install, and some personal info removed):

```
ComputerName:~ username$ touch bla
ComputerName:~ username$ ls -lae
total 72
drwxr-xr-x+ 18 username  staff    884 Oct 28 18:06 .
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x   4 root          admin    170 Oct  9 21:56 ..
-rw-------   1 username  staff      3 Oct  9 21:56 .CFUserTextEncoding
-rw-r--r--@  1 username  staff  15364 Oct 28 15:43 .DS_Store
drwx------   7 username  staff    918 Oct 27 21:21 .Trash
-rw-------   1 username  staff    224 Oct 27 21:21 .Xauthority
drwxr-xr-x   2 username  staff     68 Oct 20 16:29 .Xcode
-rw-------   1 username  staff   1116 Oct 27 21:14 .bash_history
drwx------   2 username  staff    102 Oct 11 09:38 .cups
drwx------   2 username  staff     68 Oct 20 10:34 .mozilla
-rw-------   1 username  staff     77 Oct 11 15:11 .serverauth.7216
drwx------   2 username  staff    102 Oct 11 15:11 .ssh
-rw-------   1 username  staff    621 Oct 22 14:52 .viminfo
drwx------+  4 username  staff    578 Oct 27 21:21 Desktop
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  4 username  staff    476 Oct 27 12:18 Documents
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+ 10 username  staff   3468 Oct 28 17:50 Downloads
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+ 30 username  staff   1054 Oct 11 21:36 Library
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  2 username  staff    102 Oct  9 21:56 Movies
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  3 username  staff    136 Oct 11 09:36 Music
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  2 username  staff    136 Oct  9 21:56 Pictures
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x+  3 username  staff    170 Oct  9 21:56 Public
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x+  3 username  staff    170 Oct  9 21:56 Sites
 0: group:everyone deny delete
-rw-r--r--   1 username  staff      0 Oct 28 18:06 bla
ComputerName:~ username$ cd /Users
ComputerName:Users username$ ls -lae
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   4 root          admin   170 Oct  9 21:56 .
drwxrwxr-t  22 root          admin  1122 Oct  9 22:39 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root          wheel     0 Jul  1  2009 .localized
drwxrwxrwt   2 root          wheel   136 Oct 11 09:18 Shared
drwxr-xr-x+ 18 username  staff   884 Oct 28 18:06 user
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

I did a fresh install, not as a Leopard upgrade.

Comment: Except for the *deny add_file, add_subdirectory, delete_child, writeattr, writeextattr, chown* part. I just learned about [ACLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list), thanks to you!